# jqrid keep form open after click any where

Tags: php, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

I am using JQgrid my problem is when I am click on add (+) button at that time form is open for adding records. I want to keep this form Open until and unless user click over save or cancel.

Currently It is closing when I am clicking outside of form .

I search but not found result , please help me

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `jqModal: false` option of jqGrid form editing.

You can set default options by extending `$.jgrid.edit`. For example

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    jqModal: false,       // it's the option which you need
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    closeOnEscape: true
});
```